# Use PayPal IPN multiple sites

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

Is there a way to use Paypal IPN notification for multiple urls  Or Use same IPN url on multiple web sites? I went through the paypal api documentation but could not see any such option.

Comment: I'm sure you configure your IPN with every paypal transaction request, so based on your origin, set the IPN accordingly.

Comment: @scuzzy I have set a url through the paypal dashboard.If I configure IPN notify url with every transaction request will it override the url set on through the paypal dashboard??

Comment: That's my assumption. I was looking at some code I had and I was setting the IPN for every transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **notify_url**, **return**, and **cancel_return** for each transaction. In summary:
**notify_url**: IPN URL for this particular transaction.
**return**: return URL when the transaction complete.
**cancel_return**: return URL when the user cancelled the order.

See [PayPal document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)